# Set Width of XYSeries JfreeChart

Tags: java, charts, jfreechart

Can someone help me to know how to set the width of bar in this x-y graph from JFreeChart. Thank you very much.

```
    final XYSeries series = new XYSeries("Analysis");
       series.add(22.0,33.1);
       series.add(32.0,33.1);
        series.add(42.0,33.1);
       final XYSeriesCollection dataset = new XYSeriesCollection(series);
        return dataset;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using [`createXYBarChart()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartFactory.html#createXYBarChart%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20java.lang.String,%20org.jfree.data.xy.IntervalXYDataset,%20org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation,%20boolean,%20boolean,%20boolean%29), you might experiment with the [`setMargin()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/xy/XYBarRenderer.html#setMargin%28double%29) method of `XYBarRenderer` to see if it meets your requirements.

Addendum: For example, the following lines trim 20% from the width of each bar.

```
XYPlot plot = (XYPlot) chart.getPlot();
XYBarRenderer renderer = (XYBarRenderer) plot.getRenderer();
renderer.setMargin(0.2);
```

Comment: Hello trashgod, I am working with XYSeries , and couldn't find methods in docs to setWidth, can you suggest me something. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, please provide an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits how you plot your series.

Comment: I am duplicating this example http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Chart/JFreeChartXYSeriesDemo3.htm

Comment: Can you please check my answer, I have posted a question in it.